# Косяк с append (jquery)

Tags: jquery

```html
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">
                  <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                  Add TODO Lists
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <table class="table table-borderless table2">

              </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn-primary').click(function(){
    var newTable = $(".table2").css("margin-top", "200px");
    var contentNewTable = $('table > thead').eq(0).clone(true)
    newTable.append(contentNewTable);
    });

});
```

Вопрос такой,почему в `button` и вставленной таблице сбиваются `css` свойства?

[image: картинка]

[image: Когда нажимаешь на кнопку добавления новой таблицы]

Comment: "почему в button и вставленной таблице сбиваются css свойства" - какие?

Comment: @Igor у ```div-a```, ```class="container d-flex justify-content-center"```

Comment: @Igor Вы как появляетесь сразу все понятно становится,вообщем,просто добавил отдельный ```div.container``` для таблицы и все как надо заработало.